# iOS APNS - Missing Push Notifications

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am sending notifications to apns one after the other just to test it. For example I send 20 notifications. Each time I send, a counter is incremented and its value is added to the beginning of the title in order to track delivery. The phone receives the first 5 and the 16th but none else.

I am not getting an error for any of them from the apns. They all receive success response.

Why could this be?

**EDIT (some extra info):**

I am communicating directly with https://api.push.apple.com. I am using http2 and jwtToken. And as suggested, I am keeping the connection alive.

**EDIT2:**

Device is not offline during this period.

Comment: without any code or any information about which push service are you using ? could be the entire universe

Comment: Are you using the "apns-collapse-id" header?

Comment: @Eran No, I am not using that header.

Comment: There may be short periods of the device being offline that you are not aware of.

Comment: @Eran I am sending the notifications one after another, so the total time we are talking about is less than 30 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you send the notifications in a short time period, some may be discarded, especially if the device was temporarily offline when some of the notifications were sent.

> Apple Push Notification service includes a Quality of Service (QoS) component that performs a store-and-forward function. If APNs attempts to deliver a notification and the destination device is offline, APNs stores the notification for a limited period of time and delivers it when the device becomes available again. **This component stores only the most recent notification per device and per app. If a device is offline, sending a notification request targeting that device causes the previous request to be discarded.** If a device remains offline for a long time, all its stored notifications in APNs are discarded.

([Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1))

Your app should never depend on all the notifications being delivered.

Answer (score 0):

> If you send multiple notifications for the same **bundle ID** while APNs can’t deliver the notifications, APNs preserves only one of the accepted push notifications.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/delivering_a_notification_with_apple_push_notification_service)

As you can see, the notifications you send using the same **bundle ID** can overwhelm each other even if they are waiting for a short time in APNs persistent storage.

In this case, you will not get any error message. Also, APNs do not queue up to send pending notifications. It can send randomly.